# How does one set the stop word list on an App Engine Cloud SQL database using InnoDb?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, innodb, google-cloud-sql

I am using the MySQL 5.6 version of Cloud SQL on App Engine using InnoDB.

I want to enable full text search queries, but for my application it is essential to change the stop word list. Normally in MySQL this is possible by creating a table with the stop word list and using the `innodb_ft_server_stopword_table` config setting. See [fulltext-stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

How can this be done on Google Cloud SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. For example, you have the ft_stopword_file Global variable, but you can only set it when starting the server but it's not one of the available flags that can be passed.

Comment: Thanks Mario. Please add as answer so I can accept.

Comment: Luckily, cflewis also heard you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We heard you :)

I've got some code out to enable setting `innodb_ft_server_stopword_table` in Google Cloud SQL. It'll take a couple days for it to move out to production, but you should hopefully be able to set this by the end of the week. You'll have the ability to set it using the Developer Console or `gcloud`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just in case anyone wants to know how to use  innodb_ft_server_stopword_table, they can view this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_server_stopword_table